# Copying a link in the browser and pasting it. Watir

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

I am writing an automation script for the application of the company I work for and I wanted to know how I can copy a link and paste it in the URL of my browser. This is the HTML I am working with:

```
<div data-employer="22890" data-employerjob="27544" id="email-preview"><p>Automation     Test from specialchar, has invited you to apply to the Bank Clerk position.</p>

<p>Please follow the link below to complete your application:<br>
<a href="https://staging2.clearfit.com/?ej=DEV0712-1">https://staging2.clearfit.com/?ej=DEV0712-1</a>
</p>
```

I just want to be able to copy the link "https://staging2.clearfit.com/?ej=DEV0712-1" and be able to paste it but I cannot hard code it since it will be different, and has to be, different for each iteration of the test.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the benefit of copying/pasting the link over just clicking the link?

Comment: The link it is copying and pasting is essentially a link that the user, who is currently logged in, should not have access to. It is a link that an employer uses to invite applicants to apply to his/her job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be more flexible if the  the <a> tag had an identifiable attribute.  I'm assuming that there's more than a single link on the page, so using `:index` as a locator is likely going to be very fragile.  But--for demostration purposes--this should work:

```
link_href = browser.link(:index => 0).href
browser.goto(link_href)
```